# Sentence construction with however and nevertheless

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Psychostimulant medication, such as methylphenidate, is a first-line
>   pharmacological treatment for children with attention deficit
>   hyperactivity disorder (ADHD), ***and its short-term efficacy is well
>   established*** (1). However, ***the long-term benefits of
>   methylphenidate use remain unclear*** (2); ***current treatment
>   guidelines for ADHD state that there is only evidence for
>   effectiveness of up to 2 years of treatment with methylphenidate and
>   recommend that the need for continued treatment be reviewed
>   annually*** (3). ***Nevertheless, 60% of children who start stimulant
>   treatment continue to use it beyond 2 years***(4) . (from American
>   Journal of Psychiatry)

I have enumerated the marked parts as 1,2,3 and 4.

So I was reading an article and something bothered me. I don't see any contrast between 2 and 3 even though they are in the same sentence with "however". As far as I understand, there is contrast between 1 and 2 as well as 3 and 4. I don't get it why the writers used 2 and 3 in the same sentence with a semicolon between them? If I were to rephrase it, I would choose among the versions below:

> 1- Psychostimulant medication, such as methylphenidate, is a
>   first-line pharmacological treatment for children with attention
>   deficit hyperactivity disorder (ADHD), and its short-term efficacy is
>   well established; ***however***, the long-term benefits of methylphenidate
>   use remain unclear. Current treatment guidelines for ADHD state that
>   there is only evidence for effectiveness of up to 2 years of treatment
>   with methylphenidate and recommend that the need for continued
>   treatment be reviewed annually; nevertheless, 60% of children who
>   start stimulant treatment continue to use it beyond 2 years.
>
> 2- Psychostimulant medication, such as methylphenidate, is a
>   first-line pharmacological treatment for children with attention
>   deficit hyperactivity disorder (ADHD), and its short-term efficacy is
>   well established; ***however***, the long-term benefits of methylphenidate
>   use remain unclear. Current treatment guidelines for ADHD state that
>   there is only evidence for effectiveness of up to 2 years of treatment
>   with methylphenidate and recommend that the need for continued
>   treatment be reviewed annually. Nevertheless, 60% of children who
>   start stimulant treatment continue to use it beyond 2 years.

Comment: To me, the original quote has a better flow. "However" implies contrast and is followed by a lot of words, so it is just fine if it goes into a separate sentence. "Current" appears after the statement that the treatment effects of the medication are unclear and is followed by some evidence of these effects, so semicolon keeps all the information about the evidence of the effectiveness in one sentence and thus maintains the flow of the text.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the function of "however" here. Doest it imply contrast between 1 and 2 or 2 and 3 ?

Comment: However implies the contrast between "short term effects" in the sentence (1) and "long-term effects" in the part of the sentence you have marked as ( 2).

Comment: The contrast using the word however refers to: the  short-term efficacy of methylphenidate VERSUS long-term benefits of methylphenidate use. However always contrasts the previous thing with what comes after the word however. [ADHD is an American invention for dealing with children who have not gotten proper parenting. People claim kids have ADHD and then load them up with drugs.]

Comment: @Lambie Thanks, so can't I rephrase this sentence "Our school only has Apple computers; however, some students are more familiar with PCs." to this one "However, our school only has Apple computer; some students are more familiar with PCs.

Comment: Anything that **contrasts** with what comes before it. They like him. However, we don't like them. ANYTHING. :)